# How to add relationship fields of soql query in a map of fields?

Tags: apex, soql, json

I have the following code:

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, Order__c, Question__r.Name, Question__r.Options__c  FROM Question_Stage__c';        
List<Question_Stage__c> qStages = Database.query(query);

Map<String, Object> qq = qStages.get(0).getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();

String jj = JSON.serialize(qq); //this will be sent as a response to an api call

System.debug(jj);
```

The printed result is:

```
{
  "Question__r":{
    "attributes":{
      "type":"Question__c",
      "url":"/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Question__c/a1f6D000000PbGfQAK"
    },
    "Id":"a1f6D000000PbGfQAK",
    "Name":"What is financial question 2?"
  },
  "Question__c":"a1f6D000000PbGfQAK",
  "Order__c":2,
  "Id":"a0w6D000000h4LaQAI"
}
```

Problem 1: The `Question__r.Options__c` field is missing. Why and how can I add it?

Problem 2: Is there a better way to get it in a flat json (rather than manually parsing and adding each field to a map)?

Comment: Does the running user have read access on that field?

Comment: I found out that the record I was trying to view had an empty value for the `Options__c` field, and when I added a dummy value, the returned response had the field. Can that be configured to return null or emty when the value is empty?

Comment: You are calling `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap`, since it is not populated... I think it "works as design" 

Answer (score 1):

1. You already realized this was because the data wasn't set. SObject maps only include populated field values. You would have to add missing values as null for yourself.
2. There is no default mechanism for flattening an SObject's JSON into a single Map from a Map with nested Maps for the content of relationships.

You can, however, use code like the following to do what you want for question 2:

```
public class Flattener {
    public static Map<String, Object> flatten(String jsonString) {
        Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);

        flatten(result, result, null);

        return result;
    }

    private static void flatten(Map<String, Object> root, Map<String, Object> node, String parentName) {
        for (String key : node.keySet()) {
            Object value = node.get(key);

            if (key == 'attributes') {
                node.remove(key);
            } else if (value instanceof Map<String, Object>) {
                String name = (parentName != null ? parentName + '.' : '') + key;

                flatten(root, (Map<String, Object>) value, name);

                node.remove(key);
            } else if (parentName != null) {
                root.put(parentName + '.' + key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When run with your JSON like this:

```
String jsonString = ...;
Map<String, Object> result = Flattener.flatten(jsonString);
System.debug(JSON.serialize(result));
```

This generates:

```
{"Question__r.Name":"What is financial question 2?","Question__r.Id":"a1f6D000000PbGfQAK","Id":"a0w6D000000h4LaQAI","Order__c":2,"Question__c":"a1f6D000000PbGfQAK"}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: @SachiDangalla I wasn't explicit about how this answers question 2 and that there's no built-in mechanism for this that I'm aware of. So, updated to clarify.

Comment: Oh, and it directly answers the question by its title...